# Spring Kafka Listener shutdown Application

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

I have an application that creates 3 KafkaListener per configuration in the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` if any of these Listeners throws a specific Exception. I would like to shutdown the entire spring application.

Since these errors are non recoverable and need manual intervention.
How would i go about doin this?
Do i just inject the `ApplicationContext` into the Listener and close the application from there?

Or is there a more appropriate way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

That's one way, or you could just call `System.exit(1)`.